# How To Identify Valid/Invalid Number Combination Whereas Each Combination Is Splitted Into Multi Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables

1. Valid Combination Ranges  (**ValidationTable**)
2. My Combination to Validate. (**MyListTable**)

How can identify VALID or INVALID combination in **MyListTable**? whereas each combination is splitted into multi rows by Id and Type-Id

like in below sample there are two combinations in **ValidationTable** and two combination in **MYListTable** to validate.

***sample tables and expected result:***

```
=====================
** ValidationTable **
===========================================================
| ValidRangeId | TypeId | ValidNumberFrom | ValidNumberTo |
===========================================================
|      1       |    1   |       0         |     10        |
|      1       |    2   |       50        |     100       |
|      1       |    3   |       5         |     999       |
|      2       |    1   |       100       |     200       |
|      2       |    2   |       300       |     999       |
|      2       |    3   |       400       |     999       |
===========================================================

====================
** MyListTable **
===========================================
| MyRangeId    | TypeId |    MyNumber     |
===========================================
|     10       |    1   |       8         |
|     10       |    2   |       75        |
|     10       |    3   |       500       |
|     20       |    1   |       1         |
|     20       |    2   |       400       |
|     20       |    3   |       500       |
===========================================

====================
** EXPACTED RESULT **
===========================
| MyRangeId    | Result   |
===========================
|     10       | Valid    | Combination numbers are in valid range
|     20       | Invalid  | Combination numbers are NOT in valid range
===========================
```

### HOW 10 Is Valid in MyListTable!!!

My combination becoming for Id 10,

MyNumberRange(10) => 8-75-500

And combination ranges becoming:

ValidateRange(1) => 0-50-5 to 10-100-999

ValidateRange(2) => 100-300-400 to 200-999-999

SO MyNumberRange (8-75-500) come under ValidateRange(0-50-5 to 10-100-999)

therefore 10 is Valid

### HOW 20 Is Invalid in MyListTable!!!

My combination becoming for Id 20,

MyNumberRange(20) => 1-400-500

And combination ranges becoming:

ValidateRange(1) => 0-50-5 to 10-100-999

ValidateRange(2) => 100-300-400 to 200-999-999

SO MyNumberRange (1-400-500) NOT come under ValidateRange(0-50-5 to 10-100-999 Nor 100-300-400 to 200-999-999)

therefore 20 is Invalid

***here is SQL for above tables: (Result is fixed in this SQL just to explain)***

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#ValidationTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE #ValidationTable;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#MyListTable', 'U') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE #MyListTable;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Result', 'U') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE #Result;

SELECT * INTO #ValidationTable
FROM (SELECT 1 ValidRangeId, 1 TypeId, 0 ValidNumberFrom, 10 ValidNumberTo UNION
    SELECT 1 ValidRangeId, 2 TypeId, 50 ValidNumberFrom, 100 ValidNumberTo UNION
    SELECT 1 ValidRangeId, 3 TypeId, 5 ValidNumberFrom, 999 ValidNumberTo UNION
    SELECT 2 ValidRangeId, 1 TypeId, 100 ValidNumberFrom, 200 ValidNumberTo UNION
    SELECT 2 ValidRangeId, 2 TypeId, 300 ValidNumberFrom, 999 ValidNumberTo UNION
    SELECT 2 ValidRangeId, 3 TypeId, 400 ValidNumberFrom, 999 ValidNumberTo) v 

SELECT * INTO #MyListTable
FROM (SELECT 10 MyRangeId, 1 TypeId, 8 MyNumber UNION
    SELECT 10 MyRangeId, 2 TypeId, 75 MyNumber UNION
    SELECT 10 MyRangeId, 3 TypeId, 500 MyNumber UNION
    SELECT 20 MyRangeId, 1 TypeId, 1 MyNumber UNION
    SELECT 20 MyRangeId, 2 TypeId, 400 MyNumber UNION
    SELECT 20 MyRangeId, 3 TypeId, 500 MyNumber) m

SELECT * INTO #Result
FROM (SELECT 10 MyRangeId, 'Valid' Result UNION
    SELECT 20 MyRangeId, 'Invalid' Result) r

SELECT * FROM #ValidationTable
SELECT * FROM #MyListTable
SELECT * FROM #Result
```

Comment: Should `MyRangeId` have same values as `ValidRangeId`? Please explain a bit more how you got to those expected result. Explain why 10 is Valid and 20 is not.

Comment: Should MyRangeId have same values as ValidRangeId? ANSWER IS NO its different Ids

Comment: not sure CAPS is required when commenting, it indicates that you're shouting. use **bold** to add emphasis not caps.

Comment: I apologize....!!! updated question and I explained kindly review many thxxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, check this:

```
with RI as
(
    select
        distinct(MyRangeId) MyRangeIdDistinct
    from
        MyListTable
)    
select
    RI.MyRangeIdDistinct MyRangeId,
    case
        when
        (
            select count(distinct(VT.ValidRangeId)) from
                ValidationTable VT,
                MyListTable MLT
            where
                RI.MyRangeIdDistinct=MLT.MyRangeId and
                VT.TypeId=MLT.TypeId and
                MLT.MyNumber not between VT.ValidNumberFrom and ValidNumberTo
         ) < (select count(distinct(VT2.ValidRangeId)) from ValidationTable VT2) 
         then
             'Valid'
         else
             'Invalid'
     end Result
from
     RI
order by 1;
```

Comment: Should MyRangeId have same values as ValidRangeId? ****  SO ANSWER IS= NO both tables have own ids

Comment: Then how do you identify the corresponding records? Why 1 belongs to 10 and not 20?

Comment: Ids has no role in both tables accept its helping to make a combination of numbers only,    need more detail on your Q "Why 1 belongs to 10 and not 20?"  thx

Comment: It seems to me that you are verifying records with MyRangeId=10 against valid ranges of records with ValidRangeId=1. If you would validate record (10, 2, 75) against (2,2,300,999) then it would fail, still you expect 'VALID' for MyRangeId=10. That's my question, how do you find the validation record corresponding to a specific MyListTable record?

Comment: updated question to explain how 10 is valid and 20 is invalid kindly review. many thxx

Comment: WOwwwWW....!!!!! You are the Great...!!!! many thanks its work well!!! thank you very much appreciated !!!!

Comment: I am happy I could help you!

Comment: one more favor please, can add First or Max matched **ValidRangeId** (which is matching with MyRangeId) in Result?

Answer (score 1):

Well, not much tested, and probably not the optimal solution, but the First Match could be added this way:

```
with RI as
(
    select
        distinct(MyRangeId) MyRangeIdDistinct
    from
        MyListTable
)    
select
    RI.MyRangeIdDistinct MyRangeId,
    case
        when
        (
            select count(distinct(VT.ValidRangeId)) from
                ValidationTable VT,
                MyListTable MLT
            where
                RI.MyRangeIdDistinct=MLT.MyRangeId and
                VT.TypeId=MLT.TypeId and
                MLT.MyNumber not between VT.ValidNumberFrom and VT.ValidNumberTo
         ) < (select count(distinct(VT2.ValidRangeId)) from ValidationTable VT2) 
         then
             'Valid'
         else
             'Invalid'
     end Result,
     (
        select Min(VT3.ValidRangeId) from
                ValidationTable VT3,
                MyListTable MLT3
            where
            (
                 select count(distinct(VT4.ValidRangeId)) from
                     ValidationTable VT4,
                     MyListTable MLT4
                 where
                     RI.MyRangeIdDistinct=MLT4.MyRangeId and
                     VT4.TypeId=MLT4.TypeId and
                     MLT4.MyNumber not between VT4.ValidNumberFrom and VT4.ValidNumberTo
             ) = (select count(distinct(VT5.ValidRangeId)) from ValidationTable VT5
                  where VT5.ValidRangeId=VT3.ValidRangeId) 
     ) FirstMatch
from
     RI
order by 1;
```

Comment: its working with sample but not with actual tables which I am using,  always returning NULL in FirstMatch....  there is something missing or can you please review? thx